# Visual Studio 2008 - Deploy two projects to device

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have a solution with two mobile projects. When I hit deploy only one of the app gets deployed to the device.

The output of the second project is a dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on the properties page of the project under the deployment section you can specify additional files to get deployed with your project.  Specify your DLL and you should be in business.

Comment: I could swear I looked there before, but there it is. Thanks!